# NIOSII Softcore UART Interrupt

Tags: intel, interrupt, fpga, uart, intel-fpga

I try to get an UART IP core in combination with the NIOS2 (softcore) running on the Cyclone 10 LP evaluation board.
So far everything works fine in polling mode. However, I cannot manage to get the interrupts running on the softcore.

The FPGA is configured in the following way.
[image: Quartus Platform Designer]

From the picture it can be seen, that the interrupt line is connected to the NIOS2 softcore processor.

The following picture shows that the Altera UART driver is available.

[image: NIOS2 EDS]

The initalization code provided by Altera looks like the following.

```
/*
 * Initialize the interrupt controller devices
 * and then enable interrupts in the CPU.
 * Called before alt_sys_init().
 * The "base" parameter is ignored and only
 * present for backwards-compatibility.
 */

void alt_irq_init ( const void* base )
{
    ALTERA_NIOS2_GEN2_IRQ_INIT ( NIOS2E, nios2e);
    alt_irq_cpu_enable_interrupts();
}

/*
 * Initialize the non-interrupt controller devices.
 * Called after alt_irq_init().
 */

void alt_sys_init( void )
{
    ALTERA_AVALON_JTAG_UART_INIT ( JTAG_UART, jtag_uart);
    ALTERA_AVALON_UART_INIT ( UART_0, uart_0);
    ALTERA_REMOTE_UPDATE_INIT ( REMOTE_UPDATE_0, remote_update_0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To enable interrupts you have to disable the reduced drivers in the BSP Editor of NIOS2. One might assume, that if you connect the interrupt line in Quartus Prime this will be considered in the NIOS2EDS Project. Unfortunately this is not the case.

[image]

Comment: Thx. Your answer is correct.  Today I found some details if someone wants to roll her own implementation https://community.intel.com/t5/Nios-II-Embedded-Design-Suite/Interrupt-handling/m-p/17710